# Websocket connection with apollo-server returns gibberish for connectionParams

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo

`onConnect` should receive the `connectionParams` supplied by the client and then validate that the token has not expired by checking the `token` property on the `connectionParams` object. On the client, I am sending these params as follows:

```
const subOptions = {
  reconnect: true,
  connectionParams: async () => {
    let token = await get("token")
    let ret = {
      token,
    }

    console.log("WEBSOCKET RETURN OBJECT", ret)

    return ret
  },
}

const subClient = new SubscriptionClient(subEndpoint, subOptions)
const subLink = new WebSocketLink(subClient)
```

On Client:

[image]

The object printed after "ON CONNECT" is scrambled and shows as follows. How does it end up in this format coming from the client? How can I debug this further?

On Server:

[image]

```
const ws = createServer(app)

ws.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
  // Set up the WebSocket for handling GraphQL subscriptions
  new SubscriptionServer(
    {
      execute,
      subscribe,
      schema,
      onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket) => {
        let req = {}

        console.log("ON CONNECT")
        console.log(connectionParams)

        return checkToken(connectionParams.token, function(payload) {
          return {
            user: {
              id: payload.userId,
              exp: payload.exp,
              iat: payload.iat,
            },
          }
        })
      },
    },
    {
      server: ws,
      path: "/subscriptions",
    }
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an async function for connectionParams for the moment.

Here is a workaround:

```js
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: wsUri,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
  },
});
wsLink.subscriptionClient.use([{
  async applyMiddleware(options, next) {
    const token = await getLoginToken();
    options.context = { token };
    next();
  },
}]);
```